# Функция putchar() в массив

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Всем привет)

Учусь по книге Д.Ритчи по языку Си.
Попалось такое задание (написал в комментарии кода).

По заданию нужно чтобы введённое слово (с помощью функции getchar()) вывдилось в обратном порядке.
Как сделать присваивание входного потока getchar() в массив word[i] без использования функции putchar(slovo)?

Потому что выводит в терминале как введённое слово, так и обратное (фото во вложении)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/*Напишите функцию reverse(s) которая переписывает свой строковой аргумент s в обратном порядке.
Воспользуйтесь ею для написания программы которая бы выполняла такое обращение над 
каждой строкой входного потока по очереди*/

#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

#define MAXLINE 50

void reverse (char slovo[])

  {

    int len = strlen(slovo);

    char dr_slovo[len];

      for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            dr_slovo[len-1-i] = slovo[i];
        }
    printf ("%s\n", dr_slovo);
  }

int main()

{ 

  int slovo;

  char word[MAXLINE];

  int i = 0;

  while(slovo = getchar())

    {

      if (slovo == -1)
        break;
      else if (slovo == '\n')
        {
          reverse(word);
          i = 0;
        }
      else
        {
          word[i] = putchar(slovo);
           ++i;
        }
    }  
  return 0;
 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы хотите чего-то такого?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAXLINE 50

void reverse (char slovo[])
{
    int len = strlen(slovo);
    for(int i = 0, j = len-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        char t = slovo[i];
        slovo[i] = slovo[j];
        slovo[j] = t;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[MAXLINE];
    int i = 0, c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            word[i] = 0;
            reverse(word);
            puts(word);
            i = 0;
        }
        else
            word[i++] = c;
    }
}
```

Хотя лично мне вот этот вариант нравится больше:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAXLINE 50

void reverse (char slovo[])
{
    int len = strlen(slovo);
    if (slovo[len-1] == '\n') slovo[len---1] = 0;
    for(int i = 0, j = len-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        char t = slovo[i];
        slovo[i] = slovo[j];
        slovo[j] = t;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[MAXLINE];
    while(fgets(word,MAXLINE,stdin))
    {
        reverse(word);
        puts(word);
    }
}
```

P.S. Кстати, у вас в коде имеется выход за границы массива и прочие неприятности, так что совет AlexGlebe [недостаточен](https://ideone.com/GMdo2D)...